# Команда о нагрузке на ПК и ОЗУ

Tags: linux, debian, ram

[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как называется команда, которая изображена на фото? В задании сказано, что это *известная команда для получения информации о нагрузке на компьютер, в частности на ОЗУ*. Что значит **si** и **so** в примере на картинке?

Comment: `vmstat` - команда которая выводит такие данные. `si`, `so` - swap input, swap output

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: А первая колонка (**r**) самая полезная для оценки загрузки системы. Это среднее количество процессов в очереди к процессорам